# firestore wherefield result is <FIRQuery> in swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

my code is here and result

```
  func documentField(){
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
        print(uid)
        let db = Firestore.firestore().collection("collection")
        let data = db.orderby(by: "users").whereField("users", arraycontains: uid)
        print(data)
}
```

```
console outline

MNDJR2NOx1gOcxPGJ2xOUw3PHCM2
<FIRQuery: 0x6000032555e0>
```

i dont know where is my fault this query result is every time comig `<FIRQuery: 0x6000032555e0>`

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".  Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code *creates* a query, but doesn't execute it. So that means you're printing the query itself, not its results.

If you have a look at the documentation on [getting documents from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#swift_4), you'll find this Swift example of how to do so:

```
db.collection("cities").whereField("capital", isEqualTo: true)
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }
}
```

You're going to want to call `getDocuments()` on your query in the same way and process the results you get.